# PHP Code Re-writes The Same Line Instead Of Writing To A New Line

Tags: php, file, logging, line

So I am working on a error page and I need it to log who goes to that page, when they go, what page they are accessing, and what IP they are coming from. I have successfully made it so that everything is logged to a text file in the root directory in the proper format. The only problem is that it keeps over writing what it had written the last time the page was opened rather than writing to the next line.

If anyone is wondering, this is just a test page and in reality, this specific page is copied into multiple directories that I don't want people seeing the contents of.

Here is my code.

```
<?php
$info = getdate();
$date = $info['mday'];
$month = $info['mon'];
$year = $info['year'];
$hour = $info['hours'];
$min = $info['minutes'];
$sec = $info['seconds'];
$ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
$path = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
$txt_info = "Date (DD/MM/YYYY): $date/$month/$year  Time (HH/MM/SS): $hour:$min:$sec  IP: $ip  URL: $path";


$content = "$txt_info";
$fp = fopen($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "/Access_Logs.txt","wb");
fwrite($fp,$content . "\n");
fclose($fp);
?>
```

If anyone could let me know what is happening, please let me hear what you have.

Comment: have you tried adding the "\n" to the end of the string rather than to the fwrite method so just append \n to where you're delcaring the $content variable

Comment: Suggest you open the file in mode "a" so all writes append to the end of the file.  Then fflush the file so all the data is in the file before anyone tries to write more data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

`fopen($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "/Access_Logs.txt","a");`

Notice the 'a' at the end.  That will append to the file and not re-write it.

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fopen.php

Comment: Yes! Thanks Dan. This is exactly what I was looking for! You just made my day!